# Springboot Lombok Embeddable primary Key Date

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Hello I'm trying to the build a mysql database with springboot and for one table i need a combined primary key of an id and date. My goal is versioning through the date.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Document {

 @EmbeddedId
 private docKey docKey;
}
```

is embeddable the right tool for this ?

```
@Embeddable
public class docKey implements Serializable {

 private String uId;
 private Date entryDate;
}
```

Comment: You want to provide optimistic locking in concurrent environment ?

Comment: What do you mean versioning for what purposes ?

Comment: My document has a id wich it gets identified by and a date which shows which inserted data is the newest/approved. So i can search by id and get all versions. or by Date and get the newest @MykhailoMoskura

Comment: Added answer this may help

Comment: Date it’s time when row has been inserted into database?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate specifies `@NaturalId` it’s like a surrogate key

If entity has a field which is annotated by `@NaturalId` it could be identified by primary key and by naturalId

So you can define Id as String  and an embedable class which contains Id and Date as `@NaturalId`

In this case you will able to search by Id , by Date , by Id and date

Here is documentation for `@NaturalId`:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch07.html